# Is there a convenient way of writing simple but long hex values in c?

Tags: c, hex

I'm currently writing a code where I need to modify an 8 Byte variable 1 bit at a time. I was wondering, if there's a more convenient way to write a long but simple hex value like:

> Variable & 0x8000000000000000

I know i can declare a char as 0x80 and then cast it to a different type and shift it. I'm just looking for something simpler and more practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the bit-wise left shift operator to make it more clear:

```
variable & 1ULL << 63
```

Comment: Damn me. Of course! Thank you for this. I'm not sure how I missed it.

Answer (score 1):

well, though it's a shift, but you can use arduino's [`BV()`](http://garretlab.web.fc2.com/en/arduino/inside/avr/sfr_defs.h/_BV.html) macro, that is short and convenient:

```
#define _BV(bit) (1ULL << (bit))
```

which is used that way:

```
var & (0x8 * _BV(60));
```

if you want to work on the byte furthest left or directly:

```
var & _BV(63);
```

to access 63rd bit.